# Unable to start camunda modeler 4.9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, chromium

Downloaded Camunda Modeler **linux 64-bit** from https://camunda.com/download/modeler/  version 4.9 and extracted on Ubuntu 18.04

Unable to start camunda modeler on Ubuntu 18.04

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Failed to load /data/camunda-modeler-4.9.0-linux-x64/resources/app.asar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/electron-v12.0-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node. **/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.BSbObM)**
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:2073)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/camunda-modeler-4.9.0-linux-x64/resources/app.asar/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:32:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:30)
```

I checked the GLIBC on Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ ldd --version

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) 2.27
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

How can I run camunda modeler 4.9 on Ubuntu 18.04? Please help.

Comment: Check if this program needs some requirements..

Comment: »»How can I run camunda modeler 4.9«« : Install a contemporary OS, or use a slightly older version = camunda-modeler-4.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz https://downloads.camunda.cloud/release/camunda-modeler/4.8.1/ : May 12, 2021 . ....... Opens OK with Ubuntu 18.04 .

Answer (score 2):

> camunda modeler version 4.9 extracted on Ubuntu 18.04
>
> Unable to start camunda modeler on Ubuntu 18.04

camunda-modeler-4.9.0 :     July 12, 2021.

There is a two month older version, which runs OK with Ubuntu 18.04 : `camunda-modeler-4.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz` https://downloads.camunda.cloud/release/camunda-modeler/4.8.1/camunda-modeler-4.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz :  May 12, 2021 .

Ref. https://downloads.camunda.cloud/release/camunda-modeler/ **→ →** https://downloads.camunda.cloud/release/camunda-modeler/4.8.1/

Answer (score 0):

Your post shows
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) 2.**27**

The error says: version `GLIBC_2.**29**' not found

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

(newest version here for me is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2)

As a workaround you could fall back to an older modeler version as mentioned in one of the comments: https://downloads.camunda.cloud/release/camunda-modeler/4.8.1/camunda-modeler-4.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz